# ACTION_SEND Intent with image doesn't update if draft not delete Android SMS, Hangouts

Tags: android, android-intent

Ok so I'm using the `ACTION_SEND` Intent to share and image. I'm fairly new to the work I'm doing recently - I'm sharing a bitmap, generated from a view which is saved and passed into the Intent.

Anyway, through some basic testing I've noticed that if you open up the chooser, select say SMS, and **hit back without sending** when I share another image to SMS, the previous one comes up as the attachment. Example of image attached to SMS:

[image]

The key here is that if you manually remove the image from the draft before going back, or if you send it, the next image you share will be correct. I've noticed this behaviour when sharing to SMS, Hangouts, Twitter **but not Facebook**. It's also important to mention that for SMS, Hangouts and Twitter manual removal fixes this issue for all of them, Facebook works either way.

Recap:

1. In app, hit share
2. Select SMS from chooser
3. Image is attached to message draft
4. Hit back
5. Message will be discarded --> ok
6. On a different item, hit share
7. Select SMS from chooser
8. SAME IMAGE AS BEFORE is attached to message draft

I'm not really sure where to go from here. Is this a problem on my end? Is this related to the handling of draft messages in different apps and if so is there anything I can do about it?

Below is the share code attached to the share button each list element:

```
if (holder.shareBTN != null) {
    holder.shareBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap icon = getBitmapFromView(holder.matchWrapperLL, holder.matchWrapperLL.getWidth(), holder.matchMainLL.getHeight());
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "lolhistory_sc.jpg";
            File f = new File(path1);
            try {
                if (f.exists()) {
                    // delete if exists
                    f.delete();
                }
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String path2 = "file://" + f.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("", path1);
            Log.d("", path2);
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(path2));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the referenced `getBitmapFromView` method:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int width, int height) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    // creates immutable clone
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    view.draw(canvas);

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
    return bmp;
}
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: hi alex, i have the same issue, have you solved it?

Comment: I never solved it unfortunately. It was enough of an edge case that I was OK leaving it as is. I have a feeling that this is either a bug with the receiving apps or with some default caching behaviour when receiving an image SEND intent

Answer (score 0):

Add the following flags to the Intent.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```